# Ant : using raw string - remove expanding path

Tags: xml, ant

I'm trying to execute command using ant under windows, I found that I need to use "cmd.exe" directly with my command as parameters. 
But the old syntax 'cmd -c mycommadn' doesn't work, win7 need 'cmd /C mycommand'

The problem :

```
<arg value='/C' />
```

is interpreted as 'C:' and got error 'C: : command not found'

How to force ant to be nice ?

Thanks

Comment: Loy, have you got the chance to try the solution? If so, appreciate if you can accept it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is trivial error, I believe. You have `value` instead of `line`

```
<exec executable="cmd.exe" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="/c mycommand"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: I'm disappointed : it works for me on my host, but **not** on other host with same ant version... T-T

Comment: You mean to say, you have the issue initially, and the above solution worked on your machine. Now when you test it on other machine, it has an issue. Do they have different os than you? May be provide more details.

Comment: All machine are with Windows 7 (32bits for me, 64bits on other), same ant version (1.9.2)... I can't investigate today for more information :/

Comment: Little update : ant version 1.9.4 on other host (is not a "major" version...)